# Плавная смена текста и фонового изображения по клику на кнопку

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Пытаюсь реализовать через JQ смену (еще и с анимацией, например, плавное появление) фонового изображения и текста по клику на кнопку.
Суть такая: по умолчанию, при загрузке странице, стоит фоновое изображение, например, 1.jpg на весь рабочий экран браузера и текст. Поверху, в нижней части экрана, несколько кнопок, по щелчку на которые фоновое изображение плавно заменяется изображением 2.jpg (3.jpg, 4.jpg и так далее равное количеству кнопок: каждой кнопке привязано свое фоновое изображение и текст), а также меняется текст. Использую фреймворк Bootstrap 4, но это не обязательно.
Если визуально, то понравилось, [как вот тут это реализовано](https://plus.yandex.ru/), хочется повторить хотя бы минимально тому, что написал выше. Спасибо.